# How to get the Address from Latitude and longitude using CLGecoder?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, reverse-geocoding, clgeocoder

I tried Using CLGeocoder but i am not getting the correct address. But however i tried the  same using MKReverseGeocoder and i am getting the correct address. Did anyone encounter this issue before. Is it a bug or am i going wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that CLGeocode service is having issues at the time of writing; for example some locations in southern Finland seem to get resolved to Estonia. However, the very same location gets correct address via MKReverseGeocode without a problem.